# Limitations of iOS apps designed with Flex SDK compared to XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, apache-flex

I need to make a decision as to whether I develop apps for iOS using Flex SDK or XCode. Are there any limitations to date when it comes to developing apps for iOS with Flex SDK compared to XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are numerous limitations for developing iOS apps with the Flex SDK.

Some examples:

- You don't get access to `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
- You can't change the device volume with actionscript
- You can't get network status (3G vs. wifi, airplane mode) via actionscript.

Native Extensions let you bypass some of these restrictions, but that complicates your project.

Comment: Thanks! In your experience and as someone who is new to mobile development, as I best off learning XCode or continuing down the Flex route for mobile app development? More specifically I have created a separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430720/do-i-use-air-or-native-code-for-ios-application) with the app requirements and would really appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Short answer:  It depends.  Flex is nice for being able to target iOS and Android simultaneously, but it definitely has some gotchas.