# Do I use AIR or native code for iOS application?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have been using Flex for desktop development for years. I'm new to mobile development and need to create an app for the iPhone 6 but have no idea whether I should be using Flex/AIR or native code.

The requirements of the iOS app is as follows:

- Record video to local storage within app
- Playback video from local storage within app
- Pause/seek video within app
- Overlay controls on top of the video such as TextInput, TextArea and DropDownList so user can make notes as video is being recorded
- Data entered via TextInput/TextArea/DropDownList is saved to local storage
- Option to upload video and text data to local server

Can I achieve all of this using AIR or should I be using native code?

Comment: Those kind of questions should not be asked here simply because the answer is quite obvious. If that app will never be published in anything other than Ios then make it an Ios app, if it's possible that this app might be published in other platform make it an AIR. Both will handle everything just fine.

Comment: Think about it, with AIR you create whatever app for IOS, swap out the device-specific code (minor), and it works on Android and desktop.  Explain this two-for-one deal to your next employer and see if they're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I achieve all of this using AIR?

Yes. Use `CameraUI` to capture video on the device (using the device's native camera UI), and `StageVideo` to play the video (using GPU). Overlay your app UIs (Flex or your own) to control video playback. Save local data using `File` or `EncryptedLocalStore` or `SharedObject`. Upload to a server using `File/upload()`.

> Or should I be using native code?

That's up to you. There are trade-offs, and everyone will have their own opinion. If you have a lot of experience with Flex/AS3, then you should be able to work out this app in AIR quite easily and see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Adobe AIR but performance will get a hit.

You will need a lot of effort in order to optimize performance especially for video capture functionality.

It is better to do it natively.